# Apache Dynamic Virtual Host: RewriteMap: file for map vhost not found

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, rewritemap

Following the instructions on Apache's site I have added the following to the end of my httpd.conf file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteMap lowercase int:tolower

#define the map file
RewriteMap vhost txt:/web-data/vhost.map

# deal with aliases as above
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/icons/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cgi-bin/
RewriteCond ${lowercase:%{SERVER_NAME}} ^(.+)$
# this does the file-based remap
RewriteCond ${vhost:%1} ^(/.*)$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ %1/httpdocs/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/cgi-bin/
RewriteCond ${lowercase:%{SERVER_NAME}} ^(.+)$
RewriteCond ${vhost:%1} ^(/.*)$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ %1/cgi-bin/$1 [H=cgi-script]
```

When I run `service httpd start` I get the following error:

```
RewriteMap: file for map vhost not found:/web-data/vhost.map
```

I've triple checked that the file is present, with read permissions, and that the spelling is correct in the reference. What could I be missing?

## Edit

Results of `ls -lZ` on `/web-data/`

```
drwxrwsr-x. root www  unconfined_u:object_r:file_t:s0  logs
drwx------. root root system_u:object_r:file_t:s0      lost+found
-rw-r--r--. root www  unconfined_u:object_r:file_t:s0  vhost.map
drwxrwsr-x. root www  unconfined_u:object_r:file_t:s0  vhosts
```

Comment: Could be the path to `/web-data/vhost.map`. If the relative path isn't working, try its absolute version.

Comment: `/web-data/` is a root level directory so that is an absolute path.

Comment: Are you running Linux of some flavor and have SELinux enabled by chance? Look in your syslogs if you see anything there. Examine/post the output of `ls -lZ` on `/web-data` (`-Z` displays SELinux contexts)

Comment: added to the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare the output of `ls -lZ /var/www/html` and `ls -lZ /web-data`. Also, examine your syslog, there should be a corresponding SELinux error with details.

In the interim, try the following:

1. Change the context of `/web-data` to match that of `/var/www/html` using the `chcon` command, something like:

   `chcon --reference=/var/www/html /web-data`
2. **Discouraged**: You can also *temporarily* disable SELinux and see if the error goes away

Comment: Can't find any errors related to this in any logs.

Comment: You were basically right though. I had to change my context for `/web-data/` and all it's children. I used `chcon -Rt httpd_sys_content_t /web-data/`